# In Excel how do I plot values for a changing amount of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have to calculate the x and y values of the trajectory of projectile motion based on the input variables of initial velocity and time, and plot it on a scatter plot graph. The problem I'm having is that the time value will always be different value so there's going to be a different amount of rows based on the time of the full trajectory. Is there any way to plot the values for a different amount of rows or should I just make the increment of time bigger and have the values plotted over a large number of rows?

Comment: I’m not sure what the question is.  Is it that a sufficiently large (upward) initial velocity can result in an arbitrarily long “hang time”, and, consequently, an arbitrarily large number of rows (i.e., number of data points) given a pre-determined time interval (increment)?  If so, the problem isn’t specific to graphing; you somehow need to extend the formula to enough rows for the object to get back down to the ground.  Otherwise, just set post-impact values to blank or `#N/A`.

Comment: i'm not 100% clear on the question either, but using [Dynamic Named Ranges](http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html) can help you plot ranges that have rows that grow and shrink ...